# How can I work as Selbstständiger in Germany as a non-EU citizien?

Tags: visa, germany, working-visas, immigration, working

I’m working in Germany on a work visa at the moment. My permit to stay is valid until 2026 at a certain job place. How can I change this to be self-employed in Germany? Should I go to the Immigration office and ask there?

Comment: Yes, that would be a first step in the right direction. Getting a experienced tax adviser, that specializes in self employment, would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

The German immigration law differentiates between "freelance" (single person delivers services) and "self-employed" (company owner).
In Berlin, this applies:
https://www.berlin.de/einwanderung/dienstleistungen/service.871055.php/dienstleistung/328332/en/   (freelance)
https://www.berlin.de/einwanderung/dienstleistungen/service.871055.php/dienstleistung/305249/en/   (self-employed)
Processing times here are a few months (!)
In other cities, it should be similar.

--> Your current permit for employment allows freelance/self-employment only on the side of your employment (unless it states that it's not allowed).
--> You may only start the new activity in fulltime after you received the immigration office's approval.

Comment: Most employment contracts state that it's not allowed. A better phrase would be '(only when your present employer has given their written consent)'.